# SPFx web part does not show/load in SharePoint online "_layouts/15/workbench.aspx" page in the internet explorer browser

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, pnpjs, ie

I have developed a SPFx web part for SharePoint online, while running the `gulp serve` command, this is loading in the local workbench (http://localhost:4321/temp/workbench.html), as we can see in the below screen shot:

[image]

This is also loading fine both in Mozilla and Chrome browser inside the SharePoint online on `_layouts/15/workbench.aspx` page.

```
https://globalsharepoint2019.sharepoint.com/sites/SharePointRND/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx
```

From Mozilla:

[image]

From Chrome:

[image]

But the same webparts does not display in the internet explorer browser:

As we can see if I search with **pnp** it says **"We couldn't find anything that matches your search."**

[image]

Any technical reason or limitation why the SPFx framework web-part does not show/load in the internet explorer browser from the SharePoint online (`_layouts/15/workbench.aspx`) where as it shows or loads in chrome and Mozilla browser?

Comment: Strange! Have you refreshed your browser tab after running `gulp serve`? Try pressing `Ctrl+F5`. This may sound silly question but sometimes we forget to refresh the page :P

Comment: Yes - I did multiple times of refresh, even closed and opened new session still didn't come up in ie

Comment: Are you able to see any errors in console? Open `_layouts/15/workbench.aspx` page, press `F12` first, then press `Ctrl + F5` and check if there are any errors in browser console.

Comment: Kindly can you share you github repo, while sharing repo isolate issue and upload which have issue

Comment: I am new to SPFx, I am referring this link where complete code is available. https://www.sharepoint-journey.com/SharePoint-Framework-Development-Create-List-CRUD-WebPart-PnPJS.html

Comment: Have you checked that the site is in Trusted Sites in IE settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the solution in Visual Studio Code, open **launch.json** file in "**.vscode**", modify the url for "**Hosted workbench**", then debug the code and check if the web part can show in IE browser.

If still not showing in IE, reopen the IE and try to run "**gulp serve**" again.

[image]

Comment: Is the file name "launch.json" ? I didn't find the file - what is the path of that file?

Comment: Check the screenshot in the reply above.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - however, I don't see ".vscode" folder in my project, it is missing. It seems it is a known issue ,it is reported in the below thread in GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/66630

Comment: Did you use the Visual Studio Code from here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/?dv=win ?